# Defining a function that takes a list of items and returns a coma seperated list of item names

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry, I am new to Python and stuck on this function.

```
item_pencil = {
    "id": "pencil",

    "name": "a HB Pencil",

    "description":
    "Normal pencil"
}

item_pen = {
    "id": "pen",

    "name": "a Ballpoint Pen",

    "description":
    "Standard ballpoint pen"
}
```

I have coded this function but it returns everything about the items

```
def list_of_items(items):
    n = ",".join(map(str, items))
    #n = ",".join([str(name) for name in items])
    return n

print(list_of_items([item_pen, item_pencil]))
```

The output I get

```
{'id': 'pen', 'name': 'a Ballpoint Pen', 'description': 'Standard ballpoint pen.'}, 
{'id': 'pencil', 'name': 'a HB Pencil', 'description': 'Normal Pencil'}
```

But the output I want is this

```
'a Ballpoint Pen, a HB Pencil'
```

I'm sorry if I am missing something obvious. Thanks in advance

Comment: `def list_of_items(items):
    return ",".join(i["name"] for i in items)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost close. You need to iterate through list and get the value for the `'name'` key:

```
def list_of_items(items):
    n = ", ".join([item['name'] for item in items])
    return n
```

You can use both list comprehension or generator :

```
', '.join([item['name']) for item in items])  # list comprehension
', '.join(item['name'] for item in items)     # generator expression
```

But list comprehension is both faster and more memory efficient [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/8472377)].

Comment: `str.join()` takes any iterable so you can use a generator expression instead of a list expression, ie  `n = ", ".join(item["name"] for item in items)` - this avoids building a list object for nothing.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers `str.join()` is more efficient with a list comprehension than with a generator.